# Formula or VBA for getting this to work?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I'm running reports off of a template worksheet, which I need to have a few formulas put in.  I run the reports with a macro so I don't mind including code for vba in the macro that runs the sheet, but I also don't mind plugging in the formulas to the template.  The worksheets are frozen from row 1-8 and data starts on row 9.  Each report has a different number of lines depending on what is pulled from the master data sheet.  For every row of data on the report I need to take the value in Column H, divide that number by 80, and then put the result in Column I of the same row.  Then I need to sum all of the active rows in Column I in a total box that is at the end of the report (i.e. if the report has 25 lines of data then the total box is in Column I of the 26th column)

Comment: Does it need to be a formula?  If this is just a report then could you could just insert the literal values?  You could sum the calculated values as you insert each row and then just add the total at the end...

Comment: Well, most of what I'm doing now is for ease of use for others. I'm the only one that uses the raw data on the master sheet; everyone else is interested in the parsed info that is spread out to approximately 30 sheets. I don't want to have to insert formulas into every cell that needs it on every sheet if I can help it. Since I'm using macros now to pull the information for each individual sheet I thought it might be easiest if I could add something to my existing code to perform the first calculation (I10=I9/80) and then sum everything in column I in the total cell at the bottom.

Comment: Or if I had to use formulas, I wanted to set them up in the template so that when my macro uses the template for all of the individual sheets it would carry over the formulas when it pulls all of the information from the master data sheet to the individuals.

Comment: It's difficult to offer suggestions outside of the context of your existing code: the "easiest solution" will depend on exactly what you're doing in your macro.

Comment: Does your question have a... question?

Answer (score 0):

Either way sounds just fine, it is probably more of a personal taste thing than anything. Since the resulting spreadsheets are static I would think that VBA, rather than a formula, would be fine.

You could something similar to the following for VBA:

```
dim dResult() as double

redim dresult(1 to LastRow+1)

for i=1 to lastrow
  if i>1 then
    dresult(i)=dresult(i-1)/80
  else
    dresult(i)='whatever
  end if
next i

  dresult(lastrow+1)=application.sum(dresult)

  wks.range("$I$1","$I$" & lastrow+1)=dresult
```

This is untested of course, so use it how you will. Also, you'll need to find lastrow and give it a dimension (integer or long), you'll also need to do the same for the others that i didn't dimension.